# Anyway to put a close button on an Excel graph

Tags: excel

I was wondering if there was a way of putting a close button on an excel chart, or a solution to achieve a similar objective?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Could you please invest some more care in your question's title? "Anyway" is rather unnecessary and gives off the impression that you either just stumbled out of a previous discussion (about which we don't know anything), or that you don't really care too much about the question. (Also, I *assume* you're actually referring to an Excel *spreadsheet*. Or did you really mean a chart, or graph?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward workaround would be to use a button to hide/unhide the columns that contain the chart data. This has the impact of making the chart visible/invisible

If you needed to keep the actual source data visible (say in columns A:B) , then simply grab a copy of the data in another area (columns T:U), set your graph source to the copy, and hide/unhide these columns

See [Jon Peltier's example](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/interactive-charts-with-checkboxes-and-vba/) here

Answer (score 1):

You can put a hide the chart itself with

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Visible = False
```

and of course show it again with

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Visible = True
```

or toggle with

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Visible = Not ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Visible
```

Comment: +1 A more direct approach for an absolute hide than the workaround I suggested which is geared to incremental hiding with a total hide as the final outcome.